# How do i hook keyboard events in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to make a program that opens youtube when i hit enter before and after typing 'youtube'.

I want it to run in the background without affecting the actual usage of my computer so i think i need to make the program hook keyboard events.

Does anyone know how to do this or at least which c++ headers to use?

Comment: I don't get the "before" part ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `winapi` you should have a look at [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the `WH_KEYBOARD` and `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook types. You might also have some luck using [`GetKeyboardState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you want global keyboard hooks,   have a look at something like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/keyboardhook.aspx